# Return union of keys from a object with given type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extract a union of the keys of a certain type within an object.

With my best effort, I only made it this far.

```js
export type KeysOfType<T, U> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends U ? k : never }[keyof T];
```

With that code, given `Config` and passing `boolean` as the second argument, it returns `show` as it's supposed to.

```js
type Config {
    id: string;
    show: boolean;
};

KeysOfType<Config, boolean>  // <-- Result: ('show')
```

But I can't get it to work correctly when the field is optional or based a union

```js
export type Config = {
    id: string;
    optional?: boolean;
    union: boolean | string
    show: boolean;
};

KeysOfType<Config, boolean>  // <-- Result: ('show' | undefined). Expected: ('show' | 'optional' | 'union').

KeysOfType<Config, string>   // -< Result: ('id' | undefined). Expected: ('id' | 'union')

KeysOfType<Config, boolean | undefined>  // <-- Result: ('optional' | 'show' | undefined). Expected: ('optional')
```

The result I'm expecting from that would be `'show' | 'optional' | 'union'` or at least not having undefined as there's no key called undefined

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can get rid of `undefined` by making your mapped type use the `-?` modifier, but I'm struggling to understand your logic for which keys should be returned for your examples.  Could you explain how you arrive at those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your requirements, inverting the `extends` clause and removing the optional modifier (`-?`) from your index type should get you the results you want:

```
export type KeysOfType<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: U extends T[K] ? K : never
}[keyof T];

export type Object = {
    id: string;
    optional?: boolean;
    union: boolean | string
    show: boolean;
};

type X = KeysOfType<Object, boolean>; // "optional" | "union" | "show"
type Y = KeysOfType<Object, string>; // "id" | "union"
type Z = KeysOfType<Object, boolean | undefined>; // "optional" | "union" | "show"
```

If you want to use unions, I think you do need to decide how you want the matching to work, i.e. whether it's

- `U extends T[K] ? K : never`; or
- `T[K] extends U ? K : never`; or
- `U extends T[K] ? T[K] extends U ? K : never : never`; or even
- `[T[K]] extends [U] ? [U] extends [T[K]] ? K : never : never`

Comment: Is there any way to make it more restrictive? I mean, for `type X` not to include `optional` since it's `boolean | undefined` not `boolean` or for `type Z` to be only `optional` since `union` and `show` doesn't have `undefined`.

Comment: You could go with a two way match and wrap everything in one-element tuples: `[T[K]] extends [U] ? [U] extends [T[K]] ? K : never : never`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the types that match your criteria, and then use the keyof operator to get the keys of those types.

```
export type KeysOfType<T, U> = {
[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type Object = {
    id: string;
    optional?: boolean;
    union: boolean | string;
    show: boolean;
};

type BooleanKeys = KeysOfType<Object, boolean>; // 'show' | 'optional' | 'union'
type StringKeys = KeysOfType<Object, string>; // 'id' | 'union'
```

You can also use the Record <K,V> to get it, it's a built-in type that creates a new object type with a set of properties K of type V, like below:

```
export type KeysOfType<T, U> = keyof Record<keyof T, T[keyof T] extends U ? T[keyof T] : never>;
```

Comment: I tested your solution and I still getting `undefined` within the union.

`type BooleanKeys = KeysOfType<Object, boolean>; // 'show' | undefined`
`type StringKeys = KeysOfType<Object, string>;   // 'id' | undefined`